# Android on screen timer

Tags: android, timer

I want to show a timer on the screen and the count down will continue on screen. It will also give some sound alert in certain time interval. There may be multiple timer running at the same time. What is best way to implement this type timer system? Should I run a thread for each time any timer starts and change the time display using UIThread()? There is some better way to implement it? Anyone can give me sample code for that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can implement [CountDownTimer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html).

For example:

```
new CountDownTimer(5000, 1000) {

    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
         txtView.setText(String.valueOf(millisUntilFinished / 1000));

    }
    public void onFinish() {
    }
 }.start();
```